# How to initiate a logout with MSAL2Provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am using the React Login Microsoft-Graph-Toolkit component (see snippet Below) and MSAL2Provider to log users into my Active Directory application, which works well. However, I have a requirement to logout a user from a custom logout button.  The button should be able to logout the current user session. Can anyone advise how do to initiate a login/logout using MSAL2Provider?

**Code Snippet:**

```
Providers.globalProvider = new Msal2Provider({
   clientId: "client-id"
 });
    
 <Login
   loginCompleted={(event) => {mgtSSOLoggedIn(event)}}
   loginFailed={(event) => {mgtSSOFailed(event)}}
 />
```

Comment: Hi tlockhart , as you said you already used react-toolkit for login and now you are looking for MSAL2Provider ,  could you please check the below code snippet ,is this the one you looking for ?<mgt-msal2-provider client-id="<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>"
                        login-type="redirect/popup" 
                        scopes="user.read,people.read" 
                        redirect-uri="https://my.redirect/uri" 
                        authority=""> 
    </mgt-msal2-provider> , ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/providers/msal2#initialize-in-your-html-page .

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was looking for the authentication process for MSALProvider.  Please see link for details: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/docs/getting-started.md.